# CodeIgniter pagination with this->db->query

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to use the codeigniter with $this->db->query() method?

If i use active record class i would do like this:

```
$query = $this->db->get('tb_cash_transaction',$num,$offset);
$this->db->order_by("CURRENCY_ID", "asc");
```

Now i am using the $this->db->query()

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tb_cash_transaction, tb_currency, tb_user where tb_cash_transaction.CURRENCY_ID=tb_currency.CURRENCY_ID and tb_cash_transaction.USER_ID=tb_user.USER_ID and TYPE='cash_out'";   
$query = $this->db->query($query);
```

How to implement it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this one..

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tb_cash_transaction, tb_currency, tb_user where tb_cash_transaction.CURRENCY_ID=tb_currency.CURRENCY_ID and tb_cash_transaction.USER_ID=tb_user.USER_ID and TYPE='cash_out' order by CURRENCY_ID asc LIMIT $offset , $num";
$query = $this->db->query($query);
```

Hope this will Help.

Thanks!

Hussain